# is it possible to allow merge but forbid directly committing in git

Tags: git, merge, commit

two branch in git, i use gitolite for Access control.
branch 'dev' and branch 'main'.
developers must commit to 'dev', and merge to 'main', then push 'dev'
and 'main'.
my problem is that how to only allow developers to commit to 'dev',
and merge to 'main',but can not directly commit to 'main'.
i mean if developers direcly push code to 'main',when they try to
push to remote 'main',they will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gitolite allows you to add custom server side hooks.

Use this update hook to add the check:

```
#!/bin/bash
ref=$1
old=$2
new=$3

[[ $ref == refs/heads/main ]] || exit 0

reject(){
  echo "$@"
  exit 1
}

parent=$(git rev-parse $new^)
[[ $parent == $old ]] || reject not a single commit
git rev-parse $new^2 &>/dev/null || reject not a merge commit
```

(For gitolite you have to put it into the update.secondary folder.)

Comment: Better yet, with Gitolite you can give rights to certain users.  Perhaps you could control access to merge and commit by forcing them to use a Jenkins job or some other mechanism to perform the merge/commit.

Comment: @michas,can you tell me how to distinguish merged commits. from general commits? i can only distinguish them by gitk.

Comment: A merge commit has (usually) two parents. The first one (`$new^1`) corresponds to the original branch, the second one (`$new^2`) corresponds to the other branch. If the commit is no merge commit `$new^2` is not valid and `git rev-parse` fails.

Comment: @michas,but it will not work if merge resolved as a fast-forward

Comment: A "merge" resolved as a fast-forward is no merge, it is just an ordinary commit. Always use `git merge --no-ff` to create a merge commit if you intentionally do a merge.

Comment: @michas,thanhks for yoir answer!